# Why unsubscribing an event handler from an event from inside the event handler itself makes Visual Studio think that app is running when app closes?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, event-handling, prism

I am writing an WPF application using PRISM. I am running it through debug from Visual Studio.

When I am creating the Shell, I register an event handler for the Shell's ContentRendered event. This event handler does something unrelated (that I can see is completed on the UI, just filling a ListBox with strings) then unregister the event from the event handler (which I know, in practice, is unnecessary).

If I close the application with the event handler self-unsubscribing, a few threads (that I see on the Visual Studio debug tools) are left alive seemingly forever (>10 min waiting, but the .exe seems to be gone on process explorer), so I have to manually press "Stop debugging" before being able to start the app again.

I can't figure out why this happens. Can someone please explain what is happening?

If I comment out the unsubscription on the code below, the issue is gone:

```cs
using Prism.Ioc;
using Prism.Modularity;
using Prism.Unity;
using System.Windows;
using MyTest.Views;

namespace MyTest
{
    public partial class App : PrismApplication
    {
        protected override IModuleCatalog CreateModuleCatalog()
        {
            return new DirectoryModuleCatalog() { ModulePath = @".\Modules" };
        }

        protected override Window CreateShell()
        {
            var Shell = Container.Resolve<MainWindow>();
            Shell.ContentRendered += On_Shell_First_Presentation;
            return Shell;
        }

        protected override Window On_Shell_First_Presentation(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Container.Resolve<IModuleManager>().Run();
            
            // Uncommenting line below gets visual studio stuck
            //Container.Resolve<Shell>().ContentRendered -= On_Shell_First_Presentation;
        }
    }
}
```

BTW, Am I triggering the loading of the modules the wrong way? If I don't do this, the modules are never loaded, as in, the class that inherits from IModule are constructed but neither functions defined are ever called. I sent OnDemand value on the Module attribute to False. I expected PRISM to trigger it, but I really haven't figured out why it doesn't.

**EDIT:** Per suggestion on comments, I confirmed that the way it is written actually makes a new Window object to be created but I still do not understand why this would cause this behavior. Fixing the commented line to user a proper reference to the Window instantiated on CreateShell eliminates the issue.

Comment: Just a thought.  Is "resolving" the shell creating a new one each time?  Or does prism's repo have it as a singleton?  Try either casting the `sender` parameter to type `MainWindow` in `On_Shell_First_Presentation` and using that.  Or perhaps saving in a member variable in `CreateShell` and using that.

Comment: @Joe, thanks for the suggestion. You are right, turns out that resolving Shell seems to create a new one, the constructor gets called (for information, it is a simple grid with two columns, one the listbox "menu", the other a contentregion, the codebehind class for it is nothing besides constructor calling InitializeComponent()). I guess I shot myself on the foot for not registering it as Singleton. But this defies my little understanding of DI containers, how can it resolve something I didn't register anyway? And I can't understand how to register a singleton concrete type (a View).

Comment: In my Prism app I never register my main window with the container .   I only register the view-model behind it.  I only resolve `MainWindow` one time, in the `CreateShell` function and that's it.  I guess the default behavior for `Resolve` when the item is not registered is to construct the object.  There is no need to register the `MainWindow` anyway.  You can always call `Application.Current.MainWindow` if you need to get it.  Plus, in the case of your event handler, it should already be supplied as the `sender` parameter

Comment: @Joe indeed the sender is the Window itself, just casting it works (but looks a bit strange). I found out `RegisterInstance` that enable me to register a specific instance of the window and that makes the Container return the same instance (as it is not really a service and using `RegisterSingleton` would require me to create a dummy interface class). But still, it bugs me why creating the new object seemly makes the app "leak" some threads. As far as I understand should go out of scope on the end of the event handler execution and eventually be garbage collected.

Comment: In general you want to minimize your calls to `IContainerProvider.Resolve`.  
 It is not meant to be this thing you keep around to manually resolve things.  Ideally you would only call it in the `RegisterTypes`, though that is not always practical.